# how can i use a button in closing a window?

Tags: javascript, button, window

I've been trying to implement this function on my todoList app but am coming unstuck at every try. It keeps saying that the window.close() function can't close a script file which it didn't open. Am really not sure how to get around this problem. I want a situation whereby, when i click on a button, It should close my app window.
This is my javaScript code below, please i'd like assistance on this.

```
let btnClose = document.querySelector("#close");

btnClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.open(window.location, '_self').close();
})
```

Comment: please reduce the code snippet to the important part of your question

Comment: The important part of my question is at the end of my code... The btnClose.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Change the event listener on btnClose like below to close your current window

```
btnClose.addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.close();
})
```

Comment: Tried it but it throws an error message saying "Scripts may close only the window that were opened by them"